# Ionic:error spawn "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2

at notfounderror (C:\Users\myusrname\appdata\roaming\npm\nodr_modeules\ionic\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
at verifyENOENT(C:\Users\myusrname\appdata\roaming\npm\nodr_modeules\ionic\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
at childprocess.cp.emit(C:\Users\myusrname\appdata\roaming\npm\nodr_modeules\ionic\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
at process.childprocess._handle.onexit(internal/child_process.js:198:12)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your directory is correct

For reference, this is my directory to ENOENT

> AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib

Comment: Yes it's the same.i accidentally mistyped it.

Comment: Seems like an unresolved issue as no one knows what is actually causing it according to this link [reference](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2866) . Did you try configuring the proxy in .npmrc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but somehow I got it working,I tried it by-

1.clearing cache of chrome.
2.installing node v8.9.4
3.clearing systems temp files.
Ionic v3.20 (latest till date).

Please review upon my opinion or lemme know the perfect thing that got it working,as I had seen many people getting stuck in the same error.